# Best authentication strategy for Ruby on Rails API only server (with ActiveAdmin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, next.js

I have a project where I want to develop the frontend in Next.js (requests based on fetch API from JS) and the backend in RoR and I am having a hard time to get the User authentication to work. I have researched and found four possible solutions:

- Sessions and cookies
- JWT
- devise_token_auth
- devise-jwt

I have tried to implement some of them but i always end up getting a server error on client requests at some point. I would like to know if anyone has any resources where I can get to know more about and learn more about it so I can implement such authentication in my project.

If I could take advantage of devise would be even better, since I already have it setup for ActiveAdmin (wanna use the admin dashboard)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use devise, but have since moved to AWS Cognito which handles everything for you and is customizable as needed. You might look into it.

https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/